# Zabbix missing Web Monitoring

Tags: zabbix

I installed Zabbix Server 3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 using a package.  When I go to the Configuration tab, there is no Web Monitoring option.  How do I activate that option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web monitoring is now part of host/template configuration, you can access it for each host/template. From the [Zabbix 3.2 manual](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/web_monitoring):

> Since Zabbix 2.2 web scenarios are attached to hosts/templates in the
>   same way as items, triggers, etc.

Comment: I found it. Thanks for the help.